# Redis, how to query a hash data by it's key

Tags: redis, node-redis

Suupose I have run the below using redis-cli.

```
hmset locations bangalore: '{lat: "10.32", lng: "20.10"}',
chennai: '{lat: "10.32", lng: "20.10"}',
hyderabad: '{lat: "10.20", lng: "32.21"}'
```

I can query bangalore data through redis-cli -

```
hget locations bangalore
```

How do I do the same through node?

I tried below but it returned undefined

```
client.hget("location:bangalore", function (err, obj) {
console.dir(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with node, but you tried to use `hget` to fetch the key `location:bangalore` and you didn't tell it which field from the hash.

[HGET](https://redis.io/commands/hget) is used to fetch a field inside the hash, you need to tell which field from which hash.

I imagine it goes something like this:

```
client.hget("locations", "bangalore", function (err, obj) {
   console.dir(obj);
});
```

where `locations` is a key, and `bangalore` is a field inside the `locations` hash.

Comment: It worked. There was a typo, it's location not locations. My bad.